# Xamarin Forms Can Draw ContentPage On ContentPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4yMM.png)

I want Draw Other ContentPage On ContentPage
Like Parent And Child Relationship.

Xamarin Can This?

Comment: No.  You can display a ContentView in a ContentPage.

Comment: Thanks To Reply.
and Sorry but, how can I draw ContentView in a ContentPage?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I draw ContentView in a ContentPage?

From document [Xamarin.Forms ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview),we can know:

> The Xamarin.Forms ContentView class is a type of Layout that contains
> a single child element and is typically used to create custom,
> reusable controls. The ContentView class inherits from TemplatedView.

The `ContentView` class defines a single property:

Content is a `View` object. This property is backed by a [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty?view=xamarin-forms) object so it can be the target of data bindings.
The `ContentView` also inherits a property from the `TemplatedView` class:

[ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.templatedview.controltemplate?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_TemplatedView_ControlTemplate) is a `ControlTemplate` that can define or override the appearance of the control.

The `ContentView` class  can be used to create a custom control.

The process for creating a custom control is to:

1. Create a new class using the ContentView template in Visual Studio
   2019.
2. Define any unique properties or events in the code-behind file for
   the new custom control.
3. Create the UI for the custom control.

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview .

And there is also a sample included in above document , you can check it here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-contentviewdemos/ .

Comment: Thanks For your Answer.
i Could Draw Controlview On ControlPage.